# How to add custom notification in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I have created a magento plugin and I need to add custom notification to magento admin just below the admin menu where the LATEST and CRITICAL error are shown.

I have also tried the steps from this link https://www.openstream.ch/developer-blog/adding-magento-admin-notifications-to-your-extension/. The custom notification are not shown still.

What I need is to display my custom error notification in admin section default just like how other notifications are displayed.

Can anyone tell me the steps to do that?

Comment: The link you shared does exactly what you want, so it is difficult to reproduce the issue. Can you share your code with file names and path? so that someone may be able to help you

Comment: I did the same from the link. Nothing else new. Anyhow I will post my code

Comment: have you created YourExtensionGroup_YourExtensionName.xml file in etc/modules?

Comment: Yes I have the file in etc/modules. Still I am working on it to find where the error is. My plugin works well but this notification not working. I did the same what has shown from that link.

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for the same solution. I decided to check opensource repositories and i happen to come across a working version of the "Openstream" turorial you had mentioned.

all you have to do is:

1. download the files from [here](https://github.com/openstream/notifications)
2. drop the files in your Magento app folder
3. edit the **config.xml** file with your feed address/directory
4. flush Magento cache
5. Refresh page and you should see your feed.

Here's another extension with similar features: [custom notification](https://github.com/ikonoshirt/CustomAdminNotifications)
i haven't tried this one...

I hope one of these help you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a singleton for that!

```
 ... } catch (Exception $e) {
         Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
     }
```

add the exception or whatever you want. This doesn't need to be in a try catch.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I need my custom message to display in notification area as default just like the other notification like cache, indexex and latest message.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Set Your Message.

```
Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->addSuccess("Add success message"); 
Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->addError(" Add error message");
Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->addNotice("Add notification message");
```

> 2. Display Your Message. (Optional If use custom Extension Or not Defined)

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages'); ?>
```

> 3.Define Block in Layout. (Optional If use custom Extension Or not Defined)

`<block type="core/messages" name="global_messages" as="global_messages"/>`